# styling links inside a div with a specific class

Tags: css

I am wondering how i would be able to style links inside a given div with a given class like

```
.navigation-div : a:link,a:visited {
  color:red;
  }
```

Some html

```
  <div class="navigation-div">
  <a href="home.php">Home</a>
  <a href="home.php">List</a>
  <a href="home.php">Download</a>
  <a href="home.php">Files Used</a>
  <a href="home.php">Documentation</a>
  </div>

  <div class="client-header">
  <h1><a href="home.php">CRUD Application</a></h1>
  </div>
```

Is there a selector for this kind of thing?.

Comment: Next time please show your markup, it is easier that way for the answerers.

Comment: I have added some html,sorry about that.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
.navigation-div a:link, .navigation-div a:visited {
    color:red;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZjmYT/)**