# CSS Syntax for links

Tags: html, css

I'm confused about how to only have the `a:link`, `a:visited`, `a:hover`, `a:active` apply to only some links. It doesn't seem that I can simply embed these within a class. For instance:

```
.linkstylea {
  a:link {color: #000000}
  a:visited {color: #000000}
  a:hover {color: #0000FF}
  a:active {color: #0000FF}
}
.linkstyleb {
  a:link {color: #000000}
  a:visited {color: #000000}
  a:hover {color: #000000}
  a:active {color: #000000}
}
```

Comment: don't make up new CSS syntax. Invalid syntax above.

Comment: what you are looking for is a CSS pre processor like SASS or LESS

Comment: possible duplicate of [styling links inside a div with a specific class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366357/styling-links-inside-a-div-with-a-specific-class)

Answer (score 0):

do like this ..

```
.linkstylea  a:link {color: #000000}
.linkstylea  a:visited {color: #000000}
.linkstylea  a:hover {color: #0000FF}
.linkstylea  a:active {color: #0000FF}


.linkstyleb  a:link {color: #000000}
.linkstyleb  a:visited {color: #000000}
.linkstyleb  a:hover {color: #000000}
.linkstyleb  a:active {color: #000000}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have configured it, a:link is like a css attribute of .linkstylea, which is not good.

What you need to do is found here
[styling links inside a div with a specific class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366357/styling-links-inside-a-div-with-a-specific-class)